# Bootstrap '.radio-inline' radio buttons to 'vertical' in XS mode using css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

How would you take bunch of radio buttons which are layed out well horizontally on desktop view, and change them to align vertically on mobile view **using CSS**.

this is my example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>- fellow stackoverflower, please choose a radio button</legend><br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="1" checked="checked">radio number 1
        </label>                
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="2">radio number 2
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="3">radio number 3
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="4">radio number 4
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="5">radio number 5
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/zPwSnZjDoQ

I can achieve the desired layout using JQuery with something like

```
$('label').removeClass('radio-inline').addClass('radio col-xs-offset-1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS only by modying the bootstrap `.radio-inline` class directly when the size of the screen is xs. By applying `display: block` to the class they will show as you want.

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 
  .radio-inline{
  display: block; 
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that a lot of people don't like messing with framework's classes directly. I personally don't mind (as long as it's not the padding or % of bootstrap that you're modifying)

Comment: col-xs is 768px ? you sure ?

Comment: Absolutely @Stavm. Check bootstrap grid http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and pic: https://i.gyazo.com/61ad81da0809d027e8505bf294f72b40.png

Comment: However, this is changing on Bootstrap 4, now it is <576px. If you're using V3+ use mine, V4+ 576px. Docs: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: By default, Boostrap defines `col-xs` from `767px` and down. However, it is quite common to define lower breakpoints to differentiate between very small phones and the ones that have wider screens. I personally prefer `540px` as a breakpoint, based on a lot of customer requests. Please note you can actually define your own breakpoints in Bootstrap 3 and above, including custom ones.

Comment: I agree @AndreiGheorghiu. But I think if you're modifying bootstrap classes it's a good idea to follow their settings,

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  could you elaborate on self defining screen sizes on bootstrap 3 a link maybe

Comment: [v3](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) [v4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). It's good you asked. Looks like since v3.0.1 `xs` is defined as under 480px by default :). I didn't know that. I usually use 540 px as a breakpoint on most of my Bootstrap based projects.

Comment: You don't need the online builder for it (but it's handy, I admit). You can download the source code, modify `variables.less` and recompile. This gives you the advantage of being able to add your own `autoprefixer` rules and add more packages to `grunt`.

Comment: I found I also needed this in v3: .radio-inline + .radio-inline { margin-left: 0px; }

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .radio-inline {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px; /* optional */
  }
}
```

Apparently, Bootstrap adds a `10px` left margin to `.radio-inline+.radio-inline`. In order to override that, you need a stronger selector.